# Book suggestion, to learn about Pettis's integral

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Excuse me, someone could suggest a book to me, in which I can learn about Pettis's integral? I would greatly appreciate your response.

Comment: see here for references https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article-"[On Integration in Vector Spaces](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rvhassel/Onderwijs/Old-Onderwijs/2DE08-0910/ConTeXt-OWN-FA-120909-Bib/Literature/Pettis/Pettis_Inegral_Vector_Spaces.pdf)" by..well, Pettis

and this book- "[Functional Analysis and Semi-groups](http://bookstore.ams.org/coll-31)".